# Placing an image inside a basket in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm looking for a creative way to insert image to another.

Let's take for example:

1. A basket
   [image]
2. an Apple with transparent background
   [image]

I want to put apples in the basket, and make it look natural in it. I couldn't figure out a way to do it without placing it all over the front of the basket, and not inside it.

Any creative way?

Answer (score 1):

Just turned the apple a little and added some detail to the leaf. Then sliced the non-visible part off partly by the eraser and partly by drawing a selection with the polygonal lasso tool.

The turning and the details were brushed by free hand - no effects.

This is a coarse trial to make the objects more compatible to the same image. The alternative is to fit the basket to the style of the apple (=cartoonize).

[image]

If you want several smaller apples, they must be all slightly different:

- rotated
- the leaf flipped (The apple can't be flipped because the light becomes different)
- resized
- color adjusted to keep them separate (see the leaves)

Some of them can also be redrawn to different wiewing angle, but that is not as important when there is a platoon of them. An example:
[image]

In the beginning I wrote "cartoonize". I mean emphasized edges and flat colors. An example:

[image]

The title of the question can also be taken literally. The image of the apple is warped, added to the back folded paper, shaded with BW gradients and clipped along the edge of the basket. Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? (Sorry, couldn't quite tell since you're asking for a *creative* way)

[image]

**A way to do this is**:

1. Place the apple layer on top of the basket layer.
2. Add a vector mask to the apple layer.
3. Using the pen/lasso tool or whichever tool you are comfortable with, select the part of the basket you would deem as being in front of the apple (set apple to invisible while doing so to make your life easier), and fill that area with black in the created mask.

[image]

4. If you need to adjust the apple's position, click on the 'chain' icon in between the apple and its vector mask.

[image]